# Ctrl + T doesn't work

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, add-on, shortcut

I usually used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for my Texture Setup, but it doesn't work.
I enabled my node-wrangler-add-on, but nothing changed.

I already googled for a whole while but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: is the diffuse node selected when you click Ctrl + T

Answer (score 12):

Enable the *Node Wrangler* add-on and then your shortcut will work.

Comment: Tlender **enabled** this add-on. It is in the question.

Comment: As of this writing (May 2020), the node wrangler is active by default in Blender 2.82a.

Comment: What helped me was restarting Blender after enabling Node Wrangler.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with Blender 2.82a. The shortcut does NOT work when in shading workspace and using nodes. The node wrangler addon is active (as it is now activated by standard looks like, which is great).

I wanted to use it for setting up a HDRI for lighting the scene.

Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> did not work, so I found out that you can call the node wrangler menu with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> as seen on this picture:

[image: Blender shift-w node wrangler menu]

Now to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> Add Texture setup work, you have to **first SELECT the node you want to add the texture setup to**.

This is very counter intuitive, as there is no error message like "You have to select a node for this function"

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> key binding is not used for Texture setup in the latest version of blender (2.79b). You will need to set it up manually.

Comment: This is no longer true: Blender 2.79b is not the latest version of Blender, Blender 2.8x is.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons* and search for *Node Wrangler*. Click the checkbox to enable it. Now you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]